Получить ответ, содержащий информацию о поле birth_year из схемы ресурса people в Postman
Есть API SW https://swapi.dev/api/people/4 необходимо получить ответ, содержащий информацию о поле birth_year из схемы ресурса people
"name": "Darth Vader", "height": "202", "mass": "136", "hair_color": "none", "skin_color": "white", "eye_color": "yellow", "birth_year": "41.9BBY", "gender": "male",
Можно разжевать как 5 летки, я только учусь. Я в голове понимаю что и как должно быть, но скорее не могу реализовать в Postman.

Для Йоды магистра из 9 вите иташки 5 летки разжевать нужно?

@NowhereMan какой вопрос такой и ответ

Добрый вечер! Лучше подскажите что в вопросе не так или непонятно, я повторюсь, я еще учусь. Ваши язвления считаю не уместными.

@СергейДанильчук, если вы новичок, вам следует пройти тур и почитать справку, как задавать вопросы.  В текущем виде ваш вопрос совершенно непонятен, кроме того, что вы используете Postman для доступа к какому-то ресурсу.

Вы получаете ответ в виде JSON-объекта, у которого есть поле birth_date, возвращающее результат для "стандартного" галактического календаря (см. Вукипедию), принятого во вселенной Звёздных войн (начало эпохи - битва при Явине).  Проблема ваша в чём?
